# Not able to parse object id in link

Tags: reactjs, rest

I was working on front end using react-js.  I was not able to send the pass the attribute "id" to link using react-router. I tried to send it by using . Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
NavigationDta = () => {
    return <div>
      <h5>DTA DOMAIN</h5>
        <table > 
          <tr>
             <th>DTA_MNEMONIC</th>
             <th>DTA_DESCRIPTION</th>
             <th>DEFAULT_RESULT_TYPE_DISP_KEY</th>
             <th>ACTIVITY_TYPE_DISP</th>
          </tr>

          { this.state.dta.map(object => <tr>
                                          <td><Link to="/dta/$object.id">{object.DTA_MNEMONIC}</Link></td>
                                          <td>{object.DTA_DESCRIPTION}</td>
                                          <td>{object.DEFAULT_RESULT_TYPE_DISP_KEY}</td>
                                          <td>{object.ACTIVITY_TYPE_DISP}</td>
                                          </tr>)}

        </table>


        </div>
  }
```

```
render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>      
      <div>
      {this.NavigationDta()}
      <p className="App-intro">
        <Route path="/dta/:pid" component={() => this.DtaDisplay(this.state.dta)}/>
        <Route path="/rrf" component={this.ReferenceRangeFactorDisplay}/>
      </p>
      <p className="App-intro">
        <Route path="/nomen" component={this.NomenDisplay}/>
      </p>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the link to prop to this:

```
 <td><Link to={`/dta/${object.id}`}>{object.DTA_MNEMONIC}</Link></td>
```

NOTE THE BACK-TICK (``)

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals for more info about Template literals

Comment: Thank you for replying,I did not got the answer by going through the site. Can show me how to do in this example? because i tried so much and got frustrated!!@Roy,B

Comment: yah. Thank you very much. it worked but few editions(need to add flower braces).                                              <td><Link to={`/dta/${object.id}`}>{object.DTA_MNEMONIC}</Link></td>@Roy.B